# HTTP Post Not working?

Tags: java, html, http

[My layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtLIQ.png)

I'm simply trying to get the `name` field atm because that is not even working. The `doPost` method is never called. I'm using GlassFish.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Name:</h5>
                <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/GeneralSetup.jsp" method="post">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
                    <p>Submit button.
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I test only with the name so far **without success**

```
public class FetchEnvironmentData extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

I modify the web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fetchEnvironmentData</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.atp.jsp.FetchEnvironmentData</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fetchEnvironmentData</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/GeneralSetup</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

EDIT: I change / GeneralSetup to /GeneralSetup.jsp and now I get this:

> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
>
> type Status report
>
> messageHTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
>
> descriptionThe specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested
>   resource.
>
> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.2

Comment: I updated the html. Wrong code

Comment: @Jens check now please

Comment: Don't know much about `jsp`, but your HTML posts to `GeneralSetup.jsp`, but your mapping is `<url-pattern>/GeneralSetup</url-pattern>` without the `.jsp`

Comment: @KenY-N doesnt work even with .jsp

Comment: Don't know much about jsp and servlets.... I think the problem is in the URL in form action. I think the form posts elsewhere! You can use debug tools to see if the form has posted correctly!

Comment: Edited. Now I get this error.

Comment: Change  /GeneralSetup.jsp to  /GeneralSetup in your front end call.

Answer (score 0):

Your form action points to `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/GeneralSetup.jsp` and you configure a Servlet with the URL pattern `/GeneralSetup`. So my first guess is that you simply don't call the servlet due to a wrong URL. What is the response of the server when you click the form's submit button? What do you see in the server's request log as requested URL and logged response code?

Additional questions after your edit: What exactly have you done in order to test the changed setting? Have you resubmitted the original form or have you simply clicked on Reload? The latter might produce a GET-request, leading to the error. If you want to support GET anyway you can implement `doGet` and just call `doPost` with the passed parameters.

Comment: Wait. I got something.  HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Comment: I'm not even using get method wth